# Android Studio using Git: gradle-wrapper.jar in version control

Tags: java, android, git, tfs, gradle

Android Studio  recommends using the gradle wrapper in the build work flow. However, if you are using git for version control, .jar files are ignored and are said not to be checked in, which I get. But my workflow is a little different than the average person. We are also using Team Foundation Server and git both. The gradle build gets called using a custom MSBuildTask. Here is what my .gitignore file looks like:

```
 
    # Built application files
    *.apk
    *.ap_
    # Files for the Dalvik VM
    *.dex
    # Java class files
    *.class
    # Generated files
    bin/
    gen/
    # Gradle files
    .gradle/
    build/
    # Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
    local.properties
    # Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
    proguard/
    # Log Files
    *.log
```

The way it currently works is first we pull both from TFS and our git repo into a common location, then we merge the two, check the result back into TFS and push the result back to the git repo. After this is complete, the custom MSBuildTask is executed which basically just calls "gradlew build". However, this fails because the gradle-wrapper.jar file isn't being pushed to git, its being ignored. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The .gitignore above won't ignore the wrapper files. Problem is likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter mentioned, jars are not ignored due to **your** .gitignore file; I guess the jars are ignored due to a .gitignore file located in a parent directory of your project directory. Can that be the case ?

Anyhow, if that is the case, you can try using a negation in **your** .gitignore file, something like:

```
!**/*.jar
```

In that way, you override rules from a .gitignore file in one of the parent dirs.

Comment: This worked! Thanks, new to using git and never thought about using negation.

Comment: you're welcome & enjoy git, it's a "nice partner" ;-)

Comment: this may ignore way too many jar files. you may want to just use: !gradle-wrapper.jar (https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/why-did-git-ignore-my-gradle-wrapper.html), but that is not working or me.

Comment: got it to work. make sure the !gradle-wrapper.jar is after the *.jar